# Why does Mullvad VPN asks my rootpassword when starting up?

Tags: vpn

When I start  Mullvad VPN, I'am asked for my rootpassword.
Is this normal? Does Mullvad get my rootpassword sent?

Did I configure Mullvad the wright way?

To be more clear : every time I want to use Mullvad I get a window with the text :

```
Enter your password to perform adminstrative tasks"
The application '/usr/share/mullvad/mullvad.py' lets you modify essential parts of your system
```

So I have to give my root password to go one, to use the VPN connection.

Comment: What is "Mullvad VPN"? In Ubuntu there is by default not root password set at all.

Comment: It is normal, that is how you install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not take responsibility for Mullvad but I can tell you that root permissions are required to configure network devices and that is why it might ask for your password. And it should be your password not the root password since Ubuntu usually does have a root password.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have been reading while waiting for an answer here. And indeed, it has to do with the fact that configuring network devices asks for password. And since I was using my rootpassword as user, I had to give my rootpassword. A very bad idea of me to use my rootpassword as user. I'm quit new in linux, so I learnt a lot now.

Comment: Just to get it straight: As I said Ubuntu's root password is deactivated by default. You can not login as root via password. You gain root privileges by elevating yourself to root, for example via `sudo`. To do that you have to be in the `sudo` or `admin` group and when you do it for the first time in a session you will be ask to confirm your identity by entering your password. This prevents software running as your user and other persons who might got access to your computer to gain root permissions. The password is just your user password, not the root password.

Comment: Thanks to get it more straight.I see I need to read some more about what root exactly means on Ubuntu. I do not quit understand it well.